# Is takeUntilDestroyed unnecessary on a subscription to an observable created via toObservable?

Tags: angular, angular-signals

```js
import { Component, input } from '@angular/core';
import { takeUntilDestroyed, toObservable } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

@Component({ ... })
class MyComponent {
  value = input<string>();

  constructor() {
    toObservable(this.value)
      .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed()) // is this superfluous?
      .subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

The documentation states that [toObservable](https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/toObservable) must be called in an injection context, so I am not sure whether it is automatically cleaning up subscriptions or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toObservable` implementation will use a `DestroyRef` to invoke `complete` on the observable it creates. So in a sense yes it is not necessary to have a `takeUntilDestroyed()` on it if `toObservable` is invoked in a component.

However, if `toObservable` is invoked in a service providedIn root, `DestroyRef` will never fire `onDestroy` and your observable will (almost) never be destroyed.

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
class MyService() {

 myValue = signal(5)

 getObservable() {
   return toObservable(this.myValue);
 }
}
```

This example is a great illustration of an observable that wouldn't complete automatically.